# Is using setTimer with button presses possible in autohotkey?

Tags: loops, timer, discord, autohotkey, keypress

My goal is to have a script that resets setTimer whenever I press a keyboard button just like the same thing with the mouse happening. It's so to have conversations while chatting without my mouse setting my status to afk mid-typing. Any help is appreciated.

```
#Persistent
x1:=100,y1:=1125
x2:=100,y2:=888
fD:=0

SetTimer tTimer,1000
tTimer:
  If (WinActive("ahk_exe Discord.exe") && !fD){
    If (A_TimeIdleMouse>500){
      MouseGetPos oX,oY
      MouseClick L,x1,y1,,0
      Sleep 1000
      MouseClick L,x2,y2,,0
      MouseMove oX,oY
      fD:=1
    }
  }Else If fD{
    MouseGetPos nX,nY
    If (nX!=oX || nY!=oY)
      fD:=0
  }
Return
```

Comment: I'm not really able to make sense of this. Any chance you could try to explain better what you're trying to do?

Comment: Right now this script moves my cursor over to the bottom left and does a few clicks but only if my mouse wasn't moved after a certain time which is the `(A_TimeIdleMouse>500)`. If there was a way to do that with keyboard buttons along with the idle mouse function, that would be great. So like I press K for example, you would have to wait again for half a second before the cursur moves over to the status and does the clicks.

Comment: The answer is right in front of you. There is a (A_TimeIdleKeyboard) built in Variable just like (A_TimeIdleMouse). Use that.

Comment: @Roman These A_variables surprises me everytime. Works flawlessly, thanks.